# How to add gridview into pop up window?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2010

I want to add my grid view into pop up window. My grid view consist of radio buttons.
so i want to select one of radio button and take clicked button's text value to my web page. Any one can tell me to create pop up to my sharepoint web part.
cheers !!!!

Chinthaka

Answer (score 1):

You might have some success using JavaScript. Here's a few threads that cover the basic idea. I'm no jQuery expert, but I'll bet a pretty rock there's a slick, browser-independent way to do it in jQuery.

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/282/passing-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-form39s-textbox/

http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-child3.php

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=35053